# C++ line of code with odd '& 0x3' bitwise operator

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators

I know that there are such things as bitwise operations, but it's the first time I need to deal with them. I have this code:

```
if (bonus_value + (skill_value & 0x3F) < 60)
    result = bonus_value + skill_value;
else
    result = skill_value & 0xFFFC | 0x3C;
return result;
```

Can anyone help me to make sense out of it? How could it be rewritten without all that odd bitwise stuff? I can see that this code probably does some clamping, but I am afraid to make any mistakes while rewriting it somehow.

Or it is actually important to have those here, and it does something else, rather then result clamping? What do you think?

Comment: I think that your book should have a good explanation of boolean logic and bitwise operators.

Comment: That odd bitwise stuff is a hell of a lot easier than modular arithmetic and truncation. It's really valuable to learn to understand them as things of their own.

Comment: So rather than read up on what each of the operators do, your solution to your first encounter with these operators is to try to replace them?

Comment: *"How could it be rewritten without all that odd bitwise stuff?"* -- that *odd bitwise stuff" is concise and fast (and not odd at all). It's not worth it to replace it with more (and probably slower) code. Except if you need to change its logic but this is a different story.

Comment: @axiac This is your personal opinion. Generally bit operations are not considered readable and generally should be avoided, as we should write code to show what we really intend to do. Also today compilers easily can do with optimization of code like this. This is my personal opinion. It's true, that you not always can avoid bitwise operations, but in every book of clean code it's stated to avoid as much as you can. It's not stated like this without reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take this line by line. For simplicity's sake, **we'll assume that `skill_value` is a 16-bit unsigned integer** (please provide the types next time).

```
if (bonus_value + (skill_value & 0x3F) < 60)
```

The mask here is a special case:e `0x3F` is one less than a power of two. In such cases, it can be rewritten using the modulo operator (`%`). **The condition is true if and only if `bonus_value + (skill_value % 64)` does not exceed `60`.**

```
    result = bonus_value + skill_value;
```

This should speak for itself: **if the condition is true, the result is the sum of `bonus_value` and `skill_value`.**

```
else
    result = skill_value & 0xFFFC | 0x3C;
```

This is a weird one. The `&` and `|` replace the lower six bits by `0x3C` (the `&`-mask replaces the lowest two bits by zeroes, and the `|`-mask replaces bits 2 through 5 by ones). You could achieve the same effect with `(skill_value & 0xFFC0) + 0x3C`. This new `&`-mask rounds down `skill_value` to a multiple of 64, so therefore: **if the condition is false, the result is `skill_value` rounded down to a multiple of 64, plus 60.**

```
return result;
```

And that's it. Since the question doesn't specify any *meaning* for any of these values, that's as descriptive as we can get.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (bonus_value + (skill_value & 0x3F) < 60)
    result = bonus_value + skill_value;
else
    result = skill_value & 0xFFFC | 0x3C;
return result;
```

is equivalent to

```
if (bonus_value + (skill_value % 64) < 60)
    result = bonus_value + skill_value;
else
    result = (((skill_value % 65536) / 4) * 4) | 60;
return result;
```

Comment: The expression in the `else` branch could also be rewritten as `(((skill_value % 65536) / 64) * 64) + 60`.

Comment: Thanks! I think I can try figuring it out on my own from this point. I assume, I should also should take actual value types into account? I.e., if value types is different, then  equivalent values would be different too?

Comment: @Jarod42 No, because of the `(x / 64) * 64` part (effectively `x & 0xFFC0`).

Answer (score 0):

If you convet the Hexadecimal numbers to binary -

`0x3F = 0000 0000 0011 1111
0xFFFC = 0000 0000 1111 1111 1111 1100`

you see the corresponding `&` operations aloos to get the last bits of the number.